# what to do with css top value differences in chrome and firefox?

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser, css-position, margins

The css top or margin-top values in chrome is so different with firefox and opera,what should I do?
For example in chrome when I put (top:0px;) my menu is in its right place,but in firefox I have to put (top:-80px;).

What should I do?please help;Thanks in advance.

and also firebug doesn't have any errors.
Sorry I couldn't post a jsfiddle link because the site contains lots of pictures and I reaaly wanted to post pictures so that you can understand what I mean better,I tried but I needed 10 reputation but I have only 8.

Comment: Add your code, a JSFiddle, and perhaps some screenshots. We can't help you with only the information you're providing now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset all the styling that a browser applies, then it will only apply your styling, instead of adding it's own aswell. To do this include a redet style sheet such as [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

[Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. It precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing.

Comment: or maybe i am using it in wrong way,do I have just add the style sheet to my website?